# Find the number of ways of choosing $P_1,P_2,\cdots,P_m$ such that $P_1\cup P_2\cup\cdots\cup P_m$ contains exactly $r$ elements.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> $A$ is a set containing $n$ elements. A subset $P_1$ of set $A$ is chosen. The set $A$ is reconstructed by replacing the elements of $P_1$. Then a subset $P_2$ is chosen and again the set is reconstructed by replacing the elements of set $P_2$. In this way, $m$ subsets $P_1,P_2,\cdots,P_m$ are chosen, where $m>1$. Find the number of ways of choosing $P_1,P_2,\cdots,P_m$ such that $P_1\cup P_2\cup\cdots\cup P_m$ contains exactly $r$ elements.

I first selected $r$ elements from the set $A$. Number of ways to do so is $\displaystyle\binom{n}{r}$

Now, we are left with $n-r$ elements. These elements have $2^m$ choices of going in the sets $P_1,P_2,\cdots,P_m$ but since we have already selected our $r$ elements, therefore these elements have only $1$ choice, in which they go to neither of the sets. So the final answer should be
$$\binom{n}{r}\cdot1^{n-r}$$ but this is not the correct answer in my opinion.

> The real question was to find the number of ways such that $P_1\cup P_2\cup\cdots\cup P_m=A$

If I go with my formula, I have to put $r=n$ and therefore getting the answer as $1$. But the correct answer given to this particular problem is $\displaystyle(2^m-1)^n$

I tried to generalize the question, by taking $r$ elements. What's wrong with my working$?$

And how to derive the correct answer$?$ Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the given answer is wrong. It is suspicious that $r$ is involved in the problem, but does not appear in the proposed formula $(2^m-1)^n$. I think the correct answer should be $$\binom nr (2^m-1)^r.$$

Comment: The r elements its not a part of the problem but an effort to  generalize the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given is clearly wrong as it does not depend on $r$.  I read "The set A is reconstructed by replacing the elements of $P_1.$" to mean that $P_2$ can have any collection of the elements of $A$, including those in $P_1$.  I think that is not a good way to say it, I would just say that each $P_i$ is a subset of $A$ because I don't think choosing $P_1$ deletes those elements from $A$.

You are correct to start by choosing the $r$ elements of the union, which you can do in $n \choose r$ ways.  Then the key observation is that each of those $r$ elements has to be in at least one of the $P_i$ but can otherwise be in any collection of them.  This means that each element has $2^m-1$ choices of which $P_i$ it is in.

The final answer is we have ${n \choose r}\left(2^m-1\right)^r$ choices.  The book answer is correct if $r=n$ but we are not given that.